# Minimum Methods for Ordering with Duck Typing in Python 3.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, duck-typing

In [the manual](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) is says:

> in general, `__lt__()` and `__eq__()` are sufficient, if you want the
>   conventional meanings of the comparison operators

But I see the error:

```
>       assert 2 < three
E       TypeError: unorderable types: int() < IntVar()
```

when I run this test:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class IntVar(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        if value is not None: value = int(value)
        self.value = value

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

class DynamicTest(TestCase):

    def test_lt(self):
        three = IntVar(3)
        assert three < 4
        assert 2 < three
        assert 3 == three
```

I am surprised that when `IntVar()` is on the right, `__int__()` is not being called.  What am I doing wrong?

Adding `__gt__()` fixes this, but means I don't understand what the minimal requirements are for ordering...

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: If you look at the [rich comparison method docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) it specifically mentions this behavior -- `There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, __lt__() and __gt__() are each other’s reflection, __le__() and __ge__() are each other’s reflection, and __eq__() and __ne__() are their own reflection.

Arguments to rich comparison methods are never coerced.`

Comment: @agf: Answers should be in Answers, not in comments.

Comment: @EthanFurman The docs don't walk you though the specific case like Sven's answer does, and IMO that's necessary to merit posting as an answer not just a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3.x will never do any type coercions for operators, so `__int__()` is not used in this context.  The comparison

```
a < b
```

will first try to call `type(a).__lt__(a, b)`, and if this returns `NotImplemented`, it will call `type(b).__gt__(b, a)`.

The quote from the documentation is about making comparisons work for a single type, and the above explanation shows why this would be enough for a single type.

To make your type interact correctly with `int`, you should either implement all the comparison operator, or use the [`total_ordering` decorator](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) available in Python 2.7 or 3.2.

Comment: thanks.  had completely forgotten about total_ordering.  that will do perfectly.

Comment: total_ordering works in your case. However, two different classes both using total_ordering may bug out: http://bugs.python.org/issue10042